# Jquery click event won't recognize elements from PHP list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When i load the list of items from MySQL using PHP,jquery event click won't recognize them. Jquery is working on all other elements on the page except the option tag which is created through for loop.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script src="js/js.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.option', function(e){
alert('cls2 clicked');
e.preventDefault();

});


});

</script>

<select>
 <?php
include "konekcija.php";
  $upit="SELECT * FROM galerije group by naziv_galerije";
    $rez = $connection->query($upit);


foreach ($connection->query($upit) as $r)
{
$ispis.="  <option value='{$r['id_galerije']}' class='option'> 
{$r['naziv_galerije']}</option>";
}
echo $ispis;
?>
```

Comment: What is the resulting client-side HTML from this code?  It's also pretty unusual to bind a click event to an `<option>` element.  Why not bind a change event to the `<select>` element instead?

Comment: Any errors? What do you mean with "won't recognize them"? I could not reproduce your case: works for me, although it would be better if you closed with the  `</select>` tag.

Comment: `'.option'` is selector for element with __class `option`__. I don't see any.

Comment: I have figured it out, i had to use change event instead of click.